# action can't be turned into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Why could the same action when turned into a function stop working? are there any general rules? here is a very concrete and clear example of this issue.

jQuery Mobile, http://jsbin.com/osovoh/2/edit

in this version, js works well. the label of radio button gets changed instantly.

```
var radio_elem = $('#edit-new-amount-no-cost');
$("label[for='edit-new-amount-no-cost']").html(radio_elem).append("label changed");
```

but if you remove the /* s and thus turn the same action into a function triggered by the other button,

```
function go() {
    var radio_elem = $('#edit-new-amount-no-cost');
    $("label[for='edit-new-amount-no-cost']").html(radio_elem).append("label changed");
}
```

the the same code messes formatting of the destination. what's wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

If it is inside of the function, the markup change happens AFTER jQuery Mobile renders the page. You'll have to cause jQuery Mobile to re-render the page or element you are modifying.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="WORKING: replace text in radiobutton" />
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center">
<div class="form-radios">
  <div class="form-item" id="edit-new-amount-no-cost-wrapper">
    <label class="option" for="edit-new-amount-no-cost" >
    <input type="radio" id="edit-new-amount-no-cost" name="new_amount" value="no_cost" class="form-radio"/>
    original label
    </label>
  </div>
    </div>
<input name="click to change the label" type="button" onClick="go()">
<script> 

function go(){



$("label[for='edit-new-amount-no-cost'] .ui-btn-text").html("label changed");


}

 </script>



  </body>

</html>
```